MUI material-ui - how to group a TextField and a Select?
In my app, the user needs to enter a quantity that can be in Bytes, KiB, GiB, or MiB.
I'm using 2 Reacts MUI components :

a TextField to enter the quantity
a Select to select the right quantity unit (Bytes, KiB, GiB, or MiB)

That's what I get: what I get
But as you can see there is a radius on each component. It's not nice looking.
I would like to get that :
what I woud like
I tried with form groups, but doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Does this answer your question? How to append a button to TextField in Material UI

You should use InputAdornment with Select as child. Refer this.
I have created an implementation here.

Thanks discovrer for your solution.
In the meantime I found another solution
<ButtonGroup
 fullWidth>
    <TextField
        fullWidth
        value={1}
        InputProps={{
            sx: {
                height: "50px",
                mr: 0,
                borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            }
        }}
    />
    <Select
        fullWidth
        value={1}
        sx={{
            ml: 0,
            height: "50px",
            borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
        }}
    >
        <MenuItem value={1}>Bytes</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={1024}>kiB</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={1024 * 1024}>MiB</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={1024 * 1024 * 1024}>GiB</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}>TiB</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</ButtonGroup>

